# Enable Gzip Compression with Meteor

Tags: heroku, gzip, meteor

Is there a generic way to enable gzip compression when using Meteor irrespective of whether it is hosted locally, on meteor.com or on heroku? If I wanted gzip compression just on my heroku-hosted Meteor app, how could that be enabled?

Answer (score 2):

Gzip compression does not appear to be used when running Meteor locally.

When you perform a `meteor bundle` command, the resulting bundle contains a server which uses the 'gzippo' connect middleware [1] to perform gzip compression by default.

You can view (and modify) the server file by unpacking the tarball and editing:
server/server.js.

[1] http://tomg.co/gzippo

Comment: Yes, the tarball resulting from meteor bundle is gzipped. However, 1) the packaged, combined Javascript is not gzipped, slowing initial load time, 2) More importantly, none of the client/server communications or /public contents are gzipped creating a big performance hit when publishing larger datasets.

Comment: My apologies for not being more specific in my answer.  Re: your comment, #1 is incorrect.  Of the 3 initial assets that are sent down from a production bundle, only the HTML is not gzipped.  The CSS and JS assets are combined, minified, and gzipped.  The JS being the most important as that tends to be the biggest payload.  You can verify this by noting the Content-Encoding response header via your tool of choice.

Comment: #2 you are correct.  At this time (0.5.3) each xhr response is not gzipped.  As I mentioned in the answer, the server.js file is available to modify.  Unfortunately I don't know enough about how it works to add in the gzippo filter on xhr responses.